# What LaTeX command creates an emdash?

Tags: unicode, latex, tex, ligature

I know I can create an em-dash with `---` (and an en-dash with `--`). However, I want to use these glyphs in my Unicode setup, and trying it as follows:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2012}{--}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2013}{--}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{---}
```

simply yields series of two or three dashes in the output. What should I use instead? I tried `\endash` and `\ndash`, but those are not known commands.

Comment: (1) Try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/.  (2) Try this: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf (3) Consider learning to use Google's search.

Comment: Really, Google? How does it work? It seems like, well... magic!

Comment: (4) Try this: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: This page is now the #1 Google's search result, so the world is better off with this question asked here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\textemdash` and `\textendash`